# About SSIS Flat FIle Source insert to database

Tags: ssis

I'm having a csv file which contains Member Name, Member Password for example.
But my database having a column called File Name .

My question - can I save the File Name by passing the parameter "user::FileName" into Data Flow and insert together into database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to add a `Derived Column transformation`, append a new column to your input dataset, assign the `user::FileName` variable to the new column and then map it to the columns in your destination component.